# android SQLite method malfunction(?!?!)

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I face this weird problem with SQLite; I have this dynamically generated from db, checkbox list... when  I first open my app it doesn't load properly in my Linear Layout, actually the sqlite query doesn't return any string!
But when I change fragment (from my first pane to map pane) and go back (to my first pane where I should see my checkbox list)everything works as it supposed to work and checkbox list appears! My logcat doesn't show any exception or anything suspicious...

this is my method:

```
        private int setCheckboxes(){
SQLiteDatabase database = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
        database.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());

            String queryRoutes="SELECT * FROM"+tableRoute;
            Cursor dataRoutes = database.rawQuery(queryRoutes, null);
            ArrayList<String> routesStrings = new returnMapStuff().getRoutesArray(dataRoutes);
    DatabaseManager.getInstance().closeDatabase();
            routesStrings.size();
            try{
                CheckBox cb;
                for (int i = 0; i < routesStrings.size(); i++) {
                    cb = new CheckBox(context);
                    cb.setText(routesStrings.get(i));
                    cb.setId(i);
                    ll.addView(cb);
                 }
            }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

            return routesStrings.size();
}
```

and this is how i call it:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.CheckboxLL);
int howManyCheckboxes =setCheckboxes();


this is my logcat with a few log.i():
04-01 09:22:40.883    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA CHECKBOXES?﹕ 0

//return value(setCheckboxes()) first then it runs  (inside)returnMapstuff():


04-01 09:23:00.451    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA route mesa mapstuff?﹕ paralia
04-01 09:23:00.451    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA route mesa mapstuff?﹕ petalo
04-01 09:23:00.451    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA route mesa mapstuff?﹕ partali
04-01 09:23:00.451    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA route mesa mapstuff?﹕ ateik
04-01 09:23:00.451    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA route mesa mapstuff?﹕ pagni
04-01 09:23:00.451    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA route mesa mapstuff?﹕ λύκαστος
04-01 09:23:00.451    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA route mesa mapstuff?﹕ smallville
04-01 09:23:00.451    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA route mesa mapstuff?﹕ αλί καρνέησον
04-01 09:23:00.451    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA route mesa mapstuff?﹕ καμπαμαρούν

// but when I press back (first returnMapstuff()):

04-01 09:23:04.843    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA route mesa mapstuff?﹕ paralia
04-01 09:23:04.843    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA route mesa mapstuff?﹕ petalo
04-01 09:23:04.843    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA route mesa mapstuff?﹕ partali
04-01 09:23:04.843    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA route mesa mapstuff?﹕ ateik
04-01 09:23:04.843    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA route mesa mapstuff?﹕ pagni
04-01 09:23:04.843    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA route mesa mapstuff?﹕ λύκαστος
04-01 09:23:04.843    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA route mesa mapstuff?﹕ smallville
04-01 09:23:04.843    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA route mesa mapstuff?﹕ αλί καρνέησον
04-01 09:23:04.843    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA route mesa mapstuff?﹕ καμπαμαρούν

//then return value of setCheckboxes()
04-01 09:23:04.847    2412-2412/pack.androidmap I/POSA CHECKBOXES?﹕ 9
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

`actually the sqlite query doesn't return any string!`

You miss a space here

```
String queryRoutes="SELECT * FROM"+tableRoute;
```

It must be

```
String queryRoutes="SELECT * FROM "+tableRoute;
```

Comment: no the space is there!
something happened in copy/paste... :|

Comment: Then your tableRoute is empty. Or you are not passing the correct table name.

Comment: see above (I edit the first post)... as it appears it isn't empty!